# centos mysql5.5 install via puppet

Tags: mysql, puppet, centos6

(This is a cross-post from [ask.puppetlabs.com](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/5526/centos-mysql-55/))

I am setting up a centos6.4 VM using Vagrant and Puppet. First off, my familiarity is with Debian linux and also I am new to Puppet, so sorry if I am missing something basic...

I am using the mysql module from puppetlabs, and the default version of mysql installed is 5.1 but I'd like to install 5.5.

From this post, it looks like I need to grab mysql5.5 from some extra repos,

My Puppetfile looks like:

```
forge "http://forge.puppetlabs.com"
mod 'puppetlabs/stdlib'
mod 'puppetlabs/apache'
mod 'puppetlabs/mysql'
```

I added a yumrepo declaration

```
yumrepo {
        'epel':
            descr       => 'Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch',
            enabled     => "1",
            gpgcheck    => "1",
            failovermethod => 'priority',                
            gpgkey      => "http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm",
            ;   
        'remi':
            descr       => 'Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch',
            enabled     => "1",
            gpgcheck    => "1",
            failovermethod => 'priority',
            gpgkey      => "http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm",
            ;   
    }
```

If I add package_ensure with the targeted version,

```
   class { '::mysql::server':
        package_ensure => "5.5.36-1.el6.remi",
   }
```

I can see that puppet tries to install that package, but mysql5.1 has already been installed by that point and there are dependencies that conflict. I've tried searching for a good approach, but am not familiar enough with puppet yet to know what to look for.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why you want to use 5.5 instead of 5.1...is there a good reason to do it on first place?

Comment: Furthering on the comment above, why not use MariaDB?  MySQL is on it's way out.

Comment: I just ran into this same problem. MariaDB may be an option, but the long and short is that 5.5 has a lot better performance than 5.1. You can't simply remove mysql-libs, as cron* and postfix have dependencies on it. There are some "tricks" (yum package replace) but I have my doubts that the puppet package provider can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

first to install mysql 5.5 you have remove mysql 5.1 add the following lines init.pp and moreover epel repo will not not install 5.5 on your system you need to install it with rpm of mysql to install it with rpm use add the following lines in int.pp file

```
    package { 'mysql-libs':
                     ensure => 'purged',
    }

    package { 'MySQL-server-5.5.8-1.rhel5.x86_64':
                    provider => 'rpm',
                    ensure   => installed,
                    source   => "/path_to_dir/MySQL-server-5.5.8-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm",
                    require  => Package['mysql-libs'],
    }
```